# Functions for an Uno Game (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

How can i write a canPlay function? Returns true iff other can be played on this card or vice versa.

```
class UnoCard:
    def __init__(self, color, number):
        self.Color = color
        self.Number = number

    def __str__(self):
        if self.Color == 0:
            return "Blue " + str(self.Number)
        if self.Color == 1:
            return "Green " + str(self.Number)
        if self.Color == 2:
            return "Red " + str(self.Number)
        if self.Color == 3:
            return "Yellow " + str(self.Number)

    ##def canPlay(self, other):
```

Comment: Could you give some more information on the parts you need help with or ask a specific question?

Comment: def canPlay(self, other):
   Returns true iff other can be played on this card or
   vice versa. I don't know how to write this function?

Comment: what part of that are you struggling with?

Comment: How do I compare cards? For example: green 1 on the ground. I can play Green( 1, 2, 3, ..., 9) or Blue 1, Red 1, Yellow 1.  How can i check this?

Comment: Could you not just check if the color or number is the same?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I should have had a coffee last night. :)

```
def canPlay(self, other):
    if (self.Color == other.Color) or (self.Number == other.Number):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```